# Always round up a number to a bigger side

Tags: python, rounding

I am new to Python and I'm trying to round up a number to `10000` scale.

For example:

```
a = 154795
b = a / 10000 # 15.4795
c = round(b) # 15
```

I want to round `c` to `16`, even if `b = 15.0001`, or round `a` to `160000` before passing it to `b`.

How would I be able to achieve this?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Which direction do you want to round negative numbers?

Comment: import math
print(math.ceil())

Comment: what about `numpy.ceil`?

Comment: Why would you assume OP is using `numpy`?

Comment: @0x5453, I wont have negative numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `math`'s function `ceil`. 
Here is an example:

```
import math
a = 150001
b = a / 10000
print(math.ceil(b))
```

Output:

```
16
```

Of course if you want the variable to be stored then you can use:

```
import math
a = 15001
b = math.ceil(a / 1000)
print(b)
```

For the same output:

```
16
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a difference between math `ceil()` and numpy `ceil`?

Comment: Off the top of my head, numpy's ceil accepts an extra set of parameters, most interesting a `where` one which lets you specify a condition broadcasted over the input. Also, of course `math` is a builtin.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the `ceil` function from the `math` module in python

> [**math.ceil()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil) function returns the smallest integral value greater than
>   the number. If number is already integer, same number is returned.

```py
from math import ceil
a = 154795
b = a / 10000 # 15,4795
c = ceil(b) # 16
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Dschoni said.

```py
import numpy as np

a = 154795
b = a / 10000 # 15,4795
c = np.ceil(b) # always rounds up. Gives 16 here
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard integer arithmetic way to round **up** a **positive** integer `N` divided by `D` (emphasis on up, and positive) is

```
(N + D - 1) // D
```

The new numerator term is the largest value that won't roll over to the *next* multiple of the divisor `D`, which means we can use integral floor division. For example

```
def nquot(n, d):
    # next quotient (I couldn't think of a better name)
    return (n + d - 1) // d

>>> nquot(150000, 10000)
15
>>> nquot(150001, 10000)
16
```

It's often easier to allow the conversion to floating-point and do the rounding there, as with `math.ceil` in the other answers.

---

PS. your digit grouping is weird. Both `a,bbb,ccc` and `a.bbb.ccc` are familiar, but `a.bbbc` is not.